# Extracting data from cassandra - OpenShift

Tags: cassandra, openshift

I've created the openshift web console

[OpenShift Web Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iecqy.png)

The `hawkular-cassandra` database consists of all the cluster `metrics` which is reflected in web console, However I need to extract this data from the database and store it in an `excel sheet` for analysis.

I tried to fetch this data but I am not able to access cassandra and there is no certain information regarding data `extraction` or `exporting` data to excel sheet.

Is there any way through which this can be done in open shift?